# How can I optimise / replace these 2 nested While loops in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I am new to Python so am quite pleased to have got this far! I have a dataframe (df1) with 1,700,000 records and 4 columns (e,n,o,p) + Index, which is the result of considerable preprocessing and concatenation.

Currently this code takes 2 hours to run, and clearly there is a huge difference between the intersect between 1.3m possible values of n and 700000 possible values of e reduced by a factor 
of 1000000 on the one hand and the 1.7m records on the other.

There is no other pre-processing that I can do to produce eg subsets of e, n or their intersections.

```
result = ""
cp = True
ep = 0
while ep < 700000: #700000
    np = 0
    while np < 1300000: #1300000
        df2 = df1[(df1["e"] >= ep) & (df1["e"] < ep + 1000) & (df1["n"] >= np) & (df1["n"] < np + 1000)]
        if not df2.dropna().empty:
            df3 = df2[df2.o== df2.o.min()]
            df4 = df3.drop(columns = ["e", "n", "o"])
            z = df4.to_string(header = cp)
            result = result + "\n" + z
            cp = False
        np += 1000
    np = 0
    ep += 1000
```

Sample data:

```
       p     e         n         o
15646  str0  134746.0  466842.0  421.283752
15643  str1  134229.0  466923.0  502.364410
15588  str2  134023.0  467007.0  685.986880
15645  str3  133142.0  467081.0  551.112511
15649  str4  132632.0  467511.0  132.457540
32508  str5  133995.0  607803.0  580.374017
32502  str6  133750.0  607900.0  471.699057
32509  str7  133462.0  607987.0  488.480296
32532  str8  134761.0  608314.0  320.494930
32526  str9  130148.0  608801.0  463.146845
```

The suggestion from @Błotosmętek, to use df_aux (but with the while loop, see discussion below) has made a massive improvement.

Comment: is it possible to share a representative sample of the dataset? u can then build off of the answers to ur entire dataset

Comment: Where do you define the `cp` and `result` variables?

Comment: Just dealt with both those, thank you

Comment: and just replaced 'offset' with 'o' - sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 5th line of the code you're apparently selecting a subset of records from `df1`, where value of `e` is in current `ep` to `ep+1000` range - but you do it every time in your inner loop. Moving this part to the outer loop should seriously speed things up. Another optimization is not to drop columns from `df3` but rather just select column `'p'`. I also took the liberty to replace your while loops with for loops for better legibility.

```
result = ''
for ep in range(0, 700000, 1000):
    df_aux = df2 = df1[(df1["e"] >= ep) & (df1["e"] < ep + 1000)]
    for np in range(0, 1300000, 1000):
        df2 = df_aux[(df_aux["n"] >= np) & (df_aux["n"] < np + 1000)]
        if not df2.dropna().empty:
            df3 = df2[df2.offset == df2.offset.min()]
            z = df3["p"].to_string()
            result += "\n" + z
```

Please check if results are the same as those of your original code.

Comment: Sorry, @Błotosmętek, please see above amendment

Comment: Use of for loop was **only** to improve legibility, not efficiency. What should improve efficiency is the use of `df_aux`.

Comment: i'm sorry - testing now

Comment: Your code: start 16:52:59, finish 16:54:35, 96secs, 917 result rows; Old code: start 16:58:19, finish 17:06:15, 476secs, 917 result rows. Same subset of real data - many thanks